# < operator returning true when it shouldn't

Tags: c++, sorting, comparison, operator-overloading

I'm trying to sort some enums into ascending order using the sort function (`sort(cards.begin(), cards.end());`) but it doesn't seem to be sorting them correctly. It is returning them in the order:

```
card3   {rank=SEVEN (7) suit=CLUBS (0) }
card4   {rank=TWO (2) suit=HEARTS (2) }
card5 = {rank=NINE (9) suit=SPADES (3) }
```

I suspected it was a problem with my comparison operator overloading, which is this:

```
inline bool operator<(const Card& c1, const Card& c2)
{
    return c1.getRank() < c2.getRank() &&
           c1.getSuit() < c2.getSuit();
}
```

as far as I can see, only the right hand side of that comparison is true when comparing card3 and card4 and so it should be returning false but when I `card3<card4` it returns true!

I'm probably hideously misunderstanding logic here, but this doesn't make any sense to me....

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 5):

Your comparison operator does not implement a [*strict weak ordering*](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html), which is a requirement for `std::sort`. A simple way to implement this is with a lexicographical comparison. This is made easy with [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie):

```
#include <tuple> // for std::tie

inline bool operator<(const Card& c1, const Card& c2)
{
  return std::tie(s1.getRank(), c1.getSuit()) < 
         std::tie(c2.getRank(), c2.getSuit());
}
```

You can also roll out your own in the absence of `std::tie`. The idea is that you have to handle the case where both ranks are the same.

Comment: much more elegant than my solution :D

Answer (score 3):

Typically when you compare things with two items you do it like this:

```
inline bool operator<(const Card& c1, const Card& c2)
{
    if(c1.getSuit() == c2.getSuit()) {
        return c1.getRank() < c2.getRank()
    } else {
        return c1.getSuit() < c2.getSuit();
    }
}
```

Edit... I didn't think of the actual resulting order... I guess you want to order first by Suit and then by Rank... so I've just reverted the order in my original post.